# How to save a matrix whose every element is a cell containing a 17 column MATLAB table?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Lets say I have data from a certain activity over 500 days. The duration of activity varies over those 500 days. And every day's activity is 17 columns long.

Everyday activity looks like this: 
[image: activity description]

I created a (500 X 1) mat file of zeros called 'activity_database.mat' and then I tried to do this in MATLAB:

```
clear
load 'activity_database.mat'
for v=1:500
    ////////////////////////////
    DO SOMETHING TO GET A TABLE
    ///////////////////////////
    activity_data{v}=merged_table;
    save('activity_database.mat','activity_data')
end
```

Now, after running the code. When I try to load the activity_database.mat , I receive the following error:

```
Error using load
Unable to read MAT-file C:\Users\jackryan\activity_database.mat. File might be corrupt.
```

What am I doing wrong, here? Also, the database is 50000 elements actually, so I am expecting out of space error too (about 30 GB). Is there a way to store all this data in reasonable space complexity bounds?

Comment: How important is for the cumulated data to be in the same file?

Comment: @CST-Link  I already have the script which gives out the merged table for any day requested. But right now the goal is to create a database for all the activities across all the day. It's not that important, but will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cumulating the entire data in a single file, you could actually save a file per day, in a specified order. Something like:

```
first_date = datenum(2012, 12, 20);
db_folder  = '//somewhere/over/the/rainbow/';
for v=1:500 
        %// DO SOMETHING TO GET A TABLE
        mat_name = sprintf('activity_day_%s.mat', datestr(first_date+v-1,'yyyymmdd'));
        save(fullfile(db_folder,mat_name), 'merged_table');
end;
```

You should not have problems about over-sized `.mat` files, and you can load selectively the data depending on days.

Comment: Could you add code snippet to retrieve data from the db_folder, when needed?